# \newline in p-column with extra vertical space?

Tags: tables, spacing

I need to add some vertical space between two lines in a `p`-column of a `tabular`. Outside of a table I'd use `\\[1ex]`, but inside of a table I have to use `\newline` which doesn't have an optional argument for extra vertical space. So how can I get the vertical space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works (but is obviously not for general use):

```
\makeatletter\@newline[1.1mm]\makeatother
```

`\@newline` is the internal macro that does the `\\[foo]` stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Get yourself a copy of the macro that does the real work when `\\` is found in normal circumstances:

```
\documentclass{article}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\pnewline\csname\string\ \endcsname


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|l|}
some text with\pnewline[1cm]
a forced line break
&
Second
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation. The usual definition of `\\` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\\}{...}
```

so the macro doing the real work is named `\\⍽` (with a trailing space in the name). We can access that macro with `\csname\string\ \endcsname`.

I don't think it's necessary to make `\pnewline` robust, as long as you use it only in tabular cells.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\par \vpsace{1ex}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{25em}}
    \lipsum[1] \par \vspace{5ex} \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\par` does a bit too much: The next line may be indented (by `\parindent`) and TeX executes `\everypar`.